# Pocketsphinx Android Demo Error ndk-build on cygwin

Tags: android-ndk, offline, speech, cmusphinx

I tried many solutions posted here in stackoverflow and some other forums and googled till I am totally frustrated. I am using Windows 8 with cygwin. I try to get the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo run, followed the tutorial on

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

but I had no success. What I have done:

Go through the tutorial,download all resources and installed cygwin and swig. Then, the first thing that´s not working was cd into sphinxbase folder and type command ./autogen.sh . No matter how I wrote it(./autogen.sh, only autogen.sh, only autogen etc), this doesn´t work. Ok, I then go on with the tutorial and give command configure, make and make install. This worked, but when I try to build with ndk-build, I get the next error message on the cygwin terminal:

jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:760:26: fatal error: pocketsphinx.h: No such file or directory

I changed to all posted solutions the Sphinx Path in the PocketSphinxAndroidDemo jni-folder Android.mk file. I tried all that stuff like

SPHINX_PATH :=$ /cygdrive/c/Programmierung/DeveloperLibs/CMUSphinx

SPHINX_PATH :=$ /c/Programmierung/DeveloperLibs/CMUSphinx

SPHINX_PATH := /cygdrive/c/Programmierung/DeveloperLibs/CMUSphinx

SPHINX_PATH :=$ /home/c/Programmierung/DeveloperLibs/CMUSphinx

SPHINX_PATH :=$ /cygdrive/home/Programmierung/DeveloperLibs/CMUSphinx

and so on, and so on.....nothing helped. By the way the local static libs are defined:

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := pocketsphinx sphinxlm sphinxfeat sphinxfe sphinxutil

this must be right, because this was posted many times to change the order. Even I tried it with

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)  and changed it to include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

none of this gave me a result, error still exists....what the hell could I do to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then, the first thing that´s not working was cd into sphinxbase folder and type command ./autogen.sh . No matter how I wrote it(./autogen.sh, only autogen.sh, only autogen etc), this doesn´t work.

You do not need to run autogen.sh

> This worked, but when I try to build with ndk-build, I get the next error message on the cygwin terminal:
>   jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c:760:26: fatal error: pocketsphinx.h: No such file or directory

You need to download an archive with sources, not the one named win32, which is only for Windows. The file pocketsphinx.h is contained in pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz/include.

Compiler has the concept of the "header search path" where it finds the includes. Search path is specified in the compiler command line arguments with -I option. If compiler can't find some file, most likely file is in another location or the search path is incorrectly specified. You need to put the file in the right location or specify the search path properly.

Comment: thanks for Your answer. I forgot to write it here, I had made this and put both files pocketsphinx and sphinxbase without version numbers into one folder called CMUSphinx, just like described in the cmu sphinx tutorial. There is no pocketsphinx.h file from the sources i have downloaded...nowhere.. This is because I get a little bit confused, maybe the links in this tutorial points to the wrong ones?

Comment: pocketsphinx.h is in pocketsphinx-0.8.tar.gz/include/pocketsphinx.h, you probably unpacked corrupted archive

Comment: thats the point....thank you very much. From the tutorial, it is not clear which download I should use. I am developing in Windows, so I downloaded the winzip file. And this is not the same as the tar file. Could You please set this into Your answer that this is clear for others, many thanks

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer. Great this problem is solved for you.

Answer (score 1):

Now I got it worked, I don´t like to answer my own question but maybe it helps other poeple with the same problem. Nikolay Shmyrev pointed me to the right direction, many thanks to him. Here is a little tutorial to get pocketsphinx work on windows and android:

https://sites.google.com/site/opiatefuchs/home/pocketsphinxandroiddemo

Comment: Hii Opipaefuchs i have read your above link .PocketSphinxsAndroidDemo is it able to convert the audio file to text .